# How to put thousand seperator "point"

Tags: c#, numbers, number-formatting

Since 3 days I'm searching this but I can't find something useful. I just want to format number like `12345` to `12.345` but all examples with comma, I want to use thousand seperator with "dot"

I checked this example also [Custom Numeric Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier-1) but it's working on my server but not working on customer server? Always showing with comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        NumberFormatInfo nf = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name).NumberFormat;
        Console.WriteLine(12345.ToString("N0", nf));
        nf.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
        Console.WriteLine(12345.ToString("N0", nf));
        nf.NumberGroupSeparator = "z";
        Console.WriteLine(12345.ToString("N0", nf));
```

Comment: Actually this is what i want.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the code used in conjunction with the regional settings of your machine.

If you use this code, it will use the default regional settings of your machine (if you didn't deviate in your program):

```
string s = 12345.ToString("N0");
```

If you want to use a specific culture (one that had a `.` as thousand separator), you can supply that to the method:

```
string s = 12345.ToString("N0", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nl-nl"));
```

Comment: Actually this is what i can do but i prefer something use without culture but as i understand it's impossible...

Comment: You can always change the server configuration, but your software might break in the future.